# Setting up TinyMCE textbox element

Tags: asp.net, javascript, tinymce

On the web page I try to initialize TinyMCE for a specifice asp:textbox web control.

This is the javascript in the header:

```
  tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "exact",
        elements: '<% = txtBody.ClientID %>',
```

The problem is that the txtBody control is generated inside template of DetailsView control:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Body" SortExpression="Body">           
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" Rows="10" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="400px"></asp:TextBox>                  
   </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So txtBody.ClientID can't find it on the loading stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For know I solved this like this:

For the textbox I added OnInit="txtBody_OnInit" event:

```
protected void txtBody_OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "SetEditor", string.Format("SetEditor('{0}');", ((TextBox)sender).ClientID), true);
}
```

And then put tinymce initialization inside SetEditor(theID) javascript function.

It's not the  perfect answer so if there is a better answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Put tinyMCE's loading sequence into the `onload` event.
There are more elegant ways to do this using one of the JS frameworks, but the basic way is

```
document.onload = function() { tinyMCE.init ...... }
```

in the `<head>` part of your document.

Comment: But I get compile error:The name 'txtBody' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

You can use TinyMce server control instead of a simple TextBox. You can find [here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php) or another one that written by myself, [here](http://tinymce.codeplex.com/).

Comment: downloaded tinymce_package_dotnet_1_0a2.zip, and added the dll to the toolbox, then moved the control on the page but got Error Creating Control

Comment: The type or namespace name 'ICSharpCode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Do i need to add something else beside, Moxiecode.TinyMCE.dll? (I removed the tinymce folder and  tinyMCE.init from the web page)

Comment: `ICSharpCode` is the root namespace of `CSharpZipLib` and IMO does not have any relation with TinyMce. Does it work at run-time?

Comment: no, this is the error that is displayed on compile time.
Can you please try to open web project and this control yourself?

Comment: That works for me. Are you using `CSharpZipLib` in your project?

Comment: Required installPath setting is missing, add it to your web.config. You can also add it directly to your tinymce:TextArea element using InstallPath but the web.config method is recommended since it allows you to switch over to gzip compression.

Comment: Maybe I need to set some thing in web.config? maybe i didn't download the right package(inymce_package_dotnet_1_0a2.zip)?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Yes, you should set some configuration in the web.config. Check the `tinymce_package_dotnet_1_0a2\tinymce\examples\web.config`.

Comment: Not I get this: Failed to map the path '/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js'.So DO I need the javascript folder?  I thought there is no need of it and the control has it embedded!

Comment: No, you should copy/paste the tinymce directory in the root of your application.

Comment: oh, so what is the point for this control if it's not a stand alone?

Comment: It makes using TinyMce editor simply and IMO, resolves the ClientId problem you have.

Comment: There is another way too. Set the mode to `textareas` while you have only a textarea in your page. `tinyMCE.init({ mode: "textareas",`

Comment: I have many textboxes on the page and i need to apply tinymce only on one.